# Shares in stock exchange and dividend payout relationship

Tags: bonds, dividends, shares, stock-dividend

If a company announces 22% dividend and face value of its share is Rs. 5/- what would be the payout amount for 1000 shares held by person?

Answer (score 3):

It would be 0.22 * Rs 5 per share, i.e. Rs 1.1 per share. For 1000 share it would be Rs 1.1 * 1000, i.e. 1100